# Plotting data with extremely small variation in the dependent variable

Tags: plotting

I have a dataset like

```
data = {{-5., 1.00000000000000004968}, {-4.5, 1.00000000000000004510}, 
{-4., 1.00000000000000004200}, {-3.5, 1.00000000000000004144}, 
{-3., 1.00000000000000004012}, {-2.5, 1.00000000000000003979}, 
{-2., 1.00000000000000004132}, {-1.5, 1.00000000000000004208},
{-1., 1.00000000000000004284}, {-0.5, 1.00000000000000004726}, 
{0., 1.00000000000000004284}, {0.5, 1.00000000000000004350}, 
{1., 1.00000000000000004312}, {1.5, 1.00000000000000004073}, 
{2., 1.00000000000000003956}, {2.5, 1.00000000000000004256}, 
{3., 1.00000000000000003917}, {3.5, 1.00000000000000004538}, 
{4., 1.00000000000000004671}, {4.5, 1.00000000000000004685}, 
{5., 1.00000000000000004719}}
```

However `ListPlot[data]` just gives a bunch of datapoints with constant ordinate. How can I visualize the small variations of the ordinates?

Comment: Try `ListPlot[data]`

Comment: Have you tried searching the documentation for "plot data"?  What did you find?

Comment: At risk of missing the original problem, I've edited this question. If I distorted your intent, feel free to roll back.

Comment: I don't think this should closed as a simple mistake. There is a real, non-trivail issue being raised.

Comment: I expected ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Transpose@data] to set the y-axis appropriately, but it turns out it just completely ignores it (presumably because it ignores a PlotRange where the two endpoints are "equal")

Answer (score 9):

I suggest modifying the y-coordinates by subtracting of 1.0, while compensating for that in the list plot by adding 1.0 to frame tick labels for the y-coordinates.

```
data = 
  {{-5., 1.00000000000000004968}, {-4.5, 1.00000000000000004510}, 
   {-4., 1.00000000000000004200}, {-3.5, 1.00000000000000004144}, 
   {-3., 1.00000000000000004012}, {-2.5, 1.00000000000000003979}, 
   {-2., 1.00000000000000004132}, {-1.5, 1.00000000000000004208}, 
   {-1., 1.00000000000000004284}, {-0.5, 1.00000000000000004726}, 
   {0., 1.00000000000000004284}, {0.5, 1.00000000000000004350}, 
   {1., 1.00000000000000004312}, {1.5, 1.00000000000000004073}, 
   {2., 1.00000000000000003956}, {2.5, 1.00000000000000004256}, 
   {3., 1.00000000000000003917}, {3.5, 1.00000000000000004538}, 
   {4., 1.00000000000000004671}, {4.5, 1.00000000000000004685}, 
   {5., 1.00000000000000004719}};
dataX = data[[All, 1]];
dataY = data[[All, 2]] - 1;
plotPts = Transpose[{dataX, dataY}];
divisions = FindDivisions[MinMax[dataY], 5] // N
```

> `{3.75*10^-17, 4.*10^-17, 4.25*10^-17, 4.5*10^-17, 4.75*10^-17, 5.*10^-17}`

```
ListPlot[plotPts,
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{{#, Row[{"1 + ", #}]} & /@ divisions, None}, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Turns out, this is a more interesting question, than one would realize at face value. I guess, the real question is "how to plot at better than machine precision?" +1 for going to so much trouble

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. The real problem is that `Plot`, in the end, will always have to draw at machine precision. So the data and the plot scales have to be manipulated to accommodate that fact.

Comment: I would simply draw `dataY` and emphasize (e.g., by appropriate labeling the vertical axis) that this is $y-1$. In my opinion it's easier to compreend the plot that way; one thinks of it as the magnitude of variations around 1 and can focus on the $10^{-17}$ parts, not on realizing how high above the zero each point is.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a pretty boring plot, unless you do something to visualize those very small variations in the ordinate. Maybe this can point you in the right direction:

```
data = {{-5., 1.00000000000000004968}, {-4.5, 1.00000000000000004510},
        {-4., 1.00000000000000004200}, {-3.5, 1.00000000000000004144},
        {-3., 1.00000000000000004012}, {-2.5, 1.00000000000000003979},
        {-2., 1.00000000000000004132}, {-1.5, 1.00000000000000004208},
        {-1., 1.00000000000000004284}, {-0.5, 1.00000000000000004726},
        {0., 1.00000000000000004284}, {0.5, 1.00000000000000004350},
        {1., 1.00000000000000004312}, {1.5, 1.00000000000000004073},
        {2., 1.00000000000000003956}, {2.5, 1.00000000000000004256},
        {3., 1.00000000000000003917}, {3.5, 1.00000000000000004538},
        {4., 1.00000000000000004671}, {4.5, 1.00000000000000004685},
        {5., 1.00000000000000004719}};

ListPlot[{#[[1]], Log@#[[2]]}& /@ data, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks dionys.  This will help me.

Comment: Thank you all.  All answers are helping me.

Comment: Suppose my data Set contains more than 500 points it is not working.@ m_goldberg, Corey 979.